# Cortana can't turn off WiFi

Tags: wifi, cortana, speech

Asking Cortana to "Turn off WiFi" searches information in Bing, and does not turns off WiFi as expected.

This technique works to turn off WiFi on two others phone that I've tried.

Comment: What's different about the one that's not working? Is it a different person speaking? Is there different background noise? Is the microphone clear of obstruction?

Comment: The same person is speaking. Cortana recognise the same words. on the bottom shows on both phones "turn off/on WiFi."

Comment: Was WiFi active at the time?

Comment: When saying "turn off" WiFi was enabled.
I turned off WiFi and I said "turn on"

Comment: Just tryed what you said and it did work. Just to avoid someone else downvote can you elaborate you question? Just to clarify, I'm not the downvoter.

Comment: Vitor Great!
To solve the problem I've just made a Hard Reset and set phone to US Region

Comment: I faced this problem two days ago. I tried to turn off Wi-Fi few times and it didn't work. Now, when I saw this question I told Cortana to do so, and she did with no problem. Weird right?

Comment: @Paweł Can you answer your question to make it clear?

Comment: Complain at [Cortana's UserVoice](http://cortana.uservoice.com/).

Answer (score 1):

You said that you're asking Cortana to switch off the Wi-Fi. Instead of speaking to Cortana to turn off the Wi-Fi, you try to type "Turn off Wi-Fi" to the Cortana to turn off the Wi-Fi. Check and see if it works with typing, then you try again with speaking to the Cortana.